# Adding new column to existing DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a big dataset, wanna count the words of each row and add to a new column, I couldn't find any complete answer for it, May I ask if anyone can help me?

Comment: the data is a movie review.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

As a generic answer, I'll say something like :

```
df['count'] = [len(i.split()) for i in df['row']]
```

But please provide more info on your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'article': ["aa aa aa aa", "bb bb bb", "cc cc"]
    }
)

df['count'] = df['article'].str.count('[\w-]+')
df
```

The output

```
     article       count
0    aa aa aa aa   4
1    bb bb bb      3
2    cc cc         2
```